# How do I declare a template instantiation as a friend of my class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

My `node` class needs the corresponding `linked` class to be a friend.  I wrote it as

```
template <typename T>
class node{
    T value;
    node<T> *next;
    friend class linked<T>;
};

template <typename T>
class linked{
    linked();
    ~linked();
    node<T> *head;
};
```

I get a compilation error complaining that `linked` is not a class template. How can I declare `linked<T>` to be a friend of `node<T>`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the instantiation of `linked` with the same template parameter `T` to be the friend, you need to forward declare class template `linked` at first.

```
// forward declaration
template <typename T>
class linked;

template <typename T>
class node {
    ...
    friend class linked<T>; 
    // or since C++11 you can
    friend linked<T>; 
};

template <typename T>
class linked {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the class linked as follows ahead of using it in Node class.  But your code looks more messy than just this issue. And I am not sure what you are actually attempting.

```
template <typename T>
class linked;

template <typename T>
class node{
    private:
    T value;
    node<T> *next;
    friend class linked<T>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that where the statement `friend class linked<T>;` appears, the `linked` class has not been declared. Add the following before `class node`.

```
template <typename T>
class linked;
```